# Visual Studio 2015 IntelliTest: The selected type is not visible and cannot be explored

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, intellitest

I have the following code :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var area = AreaofSquare(5.0);
    }

    static double AreaofSquare(double side)
    {
        double area;
        area = Math.Pow(side, 2);
        return area;
    }
}
```

When I right click on the `AreaofSquare` method and select Run IntelliTest, I get this error message:

> The selected type is not visible and cannot be explored

Why this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IntelliTest only works with public methods. Change the access modifier to public and it works.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var area = AreaofSquare(5.0);
    }

    public static double AreaofSquare(double side)
    {
        double area;
        area = Math.Pow(side, 2);
        return area;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with the Visual Studio 2015 RTM release, we have added a "Create IntelliTest" command. This command can be run on non-public members as well, and emits a parameterized unit test and the necessary InternalsVisibleTo attributes. You can subsequently invoke the "Run IntelliTest" command on this parameterized unit test or its associated code-under-test and explore it. Please see here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/07/25/unit-test-generators-extensibility-hats-off-to-our-community.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0, for context.